# Postfix multi IP/Domain SMTP Helo'ing

Tags: linux, email, postfix, smtp

We have `Postfix` running with two domain and each domain has own IP so it's isolated.

But `Spamhuaus` blocked my IP and saying you are sending "localhost.localdomain" `HELO`

I am already using `smtp_helo_name` SMTP option

How do i tell my postfix send specific domain related `HELO` when sending email? I have following config in `master.conf`

```
#smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
127.0.0.1:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-localhost
      -o smtp_helo_name=localhost
      -o smtp_bind_address=127.0.0.1
      -o myhostname=localhost

65.xxx.xxx.100:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.abc.com
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.abc.com
      -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.100
      -o myhostname=mail.abc.com

65.xxx.xxx.200:smtp inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd
      -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.xyz.com
      -o smtp_helo_name=mail.zyx.com
      -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.200
      -o myhostname=mail.xyz.com

abc-out  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.100
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.abc.com
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.abc.com

xyz-out  unix -       -       n       -       -       smtp
   -o smtp_bind_address=65.xxx.xxx.200
   -o smtp_helo_name=mail.xyz.com
   -o syslog_name=postfix-mail.xyz.com
```